# noclassdeffound error in java, linux

Tags: java, linux, jdbc

running a java class by shell script:

```
java -cp $CLASSPATH CG_GpsRequest "dbname","oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver","abc","abc"
```

while running the script in unix, getting error,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: CG_GpsRequest
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
```

`CG_GpsRequest` is the class file name.

Comment: Could you share what does $CLASSPATH expands to?

Comment: $CLASSPATH=/java/jre/lib

Answer (score 1):

Okay.. If I understand you correctly..

I think its problem with the Package name specification..

Your calss `CG_GpsRequest` you must have specified in Packaging way for example

```
com.xxx.yyy.CG_GpsRequest
```

So I think `JVM` is searching your class `com.xxx.yyy.CG_GpsRequest` in this patter so Please  run your script with the following modifications.

```
java -cp $CLASSPATH com.xxx.yyy.CG_GpsRequest  "dbname","oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver","abc","abc"
```

This is just assumption that you have created your class in Pacakgin hirarechy since you havent specified more information.

Comment: your assumption is correct about package hierarchy, but I have maintaned the proper hierarchy which I have mentioned in the java file. So, the error must not have occurred from that side

Comment: May be you did not get What I mean, when you are running your java class you should specify your class along with package hirarechy Like I have explained in my answer ..

Comment: Yeah, now I got your point. It was helpful... now I am able to run that class file. Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

Add the folder/path in which your java class exists to your CLASSPATH

Comment: CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/Scripts/class_files

after doing this, still i'm getting same error